# Sorting a column ascending and descending by clicking on the column's header using javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, testcomplete

I need help to create a javascript function that allow me to sort a column (table) by clicking on the column header. The column contains 8 digit number and several rows. I need to sort it ascending and then descending with a verification to make sure the sort did work and also log the sort for each.

I am using TestComplete with javascript scripting.

**Example of verification:**

//Verify the sort functionality

```
       for (var k = 0; i < records.length; k++)
        {
        if(column[k] != column_sorted[k])
        Log.Warning("Sort functionality does not work for the column")
   
        break;
       }
       Log.Checkpoint("Sort functionality works for the column")
         Log.Message(column_sorted[k].contentText);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this homework or something?  There are a lot of frameworks and ready-made server controls that can take care of this for you.

Comment: Or if you are using .Net the GridView server control.

Comment: @Seano666 why are you mentioning .NET? It's not specified in the question or tags.

Comment: Did you try recording your actions in TestComplete?

Comment: To others: This question isn't about JavaScript in browsers. It's about automated web testing (GUI automation) using TestComplete.

Answer (score 1):

A simple table sorter isn't that hard. The trick is in getting the right sorting function, the rest is fairly straight forward. The following shows how to sort a table with a column of numbers, how much more functionality you add it up to you.

Some test HTML:

```
<table id="t0">
  <tr><td>44444444
  <tr><td>66666666
  <tr><td>33333333
  <tr><td>77777777
  <tr><td>11111111
  <tr><td>55555555
  <tr><td>22222222
</table>

<button onclick="sortRows(document.getElementById('t0'));">Sort</button>
<button onclick="sortRows(document.getElementById('t0'), true);">Sort reverse</button>
```

and script

```
// Sort table rows by the first cell (index 0)
// Setting reverse to true sorts in reverse
function sortRows(table, reverse) {

  // Get the rows, this gets all rows in a table but can be
  // restricted to those within a table section
  var row, rows = table.rows;
  var cells = [];
  reverse = !!reverse;

  // Get cells to sort and load into array
  // Gets the first cell in each row, but could use the cell index
  // of a header cell that was clicked on
  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    cells.push(rows[i].cells[0]);
  }

  // Sort the cells as numbers
  // or any other sort algorithm (e.g. date, alphabetic, etc.)
  cells.sort(function(a, b) {
    return getText(a) - getText(b);
  });

  // Reverse if required
  if (reverse) cells.reverse();

  // Order rows based on new order of cells
  // This works within a table section, making it easy to exclude
  // header and footer rows
  for (var j=0, jLen=cells.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    row = cells[j].parentNode;
    row.parentNode.appendChild(row);
  }
}

// A simple helper as textContent is not supported by all browsers in use
// Can be much more sophisticated and trim whitespace
function getText(el) {
  return el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a tall order. You may want to use a library for this, such as TableSorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Answer (score 0):

If you already put the values of the column to an array, you can simply use the JScript [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b4fbfhk(v=vs.84).aspx) method to sort this array ascending. If you need to perform descending sorting, you need to use a simple custom sorting function.

```
function test()
{
  var records = new Array();
  records.push(92749283);
  records.push(47932729);
  records.push(12309334);
  records.push(84932889);

  Log.Message("Ascending");
  records.sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    Log.Message(records[i]);

  Log.Message("Descending");
  records.sort(sortDesc);
  for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    Log.Message(records[i]);
}

function sortDesc(a, b)
{
  if (a > b) return -1;
  if (a < b) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the javaScript sort() readymade function. It will reduce the lines of code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Hi @Pratiksha Samane, Would you mind adding an example code?